# Derive BLEU score for corpus from sentence-level scores

Tags: python, nltk, bleu

I want to calculate BLEU score for a corpus.

Due to some problems, I had to use sentence-level BLEU score rather than corpus-level BLEU. I have used `nltk.translate.bleu_score.sentence_bleu` in python to compute BLEU score for each sentence, and now I’d like to assign a score to the whole corpus.

How should I integerate partial scores? Should I use geometric average or something else?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Then it wouldn't exact be BLEU. BLEU score was originally a corpus-level score. Sentence level BLEU falls into 101 problems and smoothing is required to make sentence BLEU works properly. And trying to take some sort  of mean to the sentence BLEU to derive corpus BLEU is rather crude and would have totally made it another shade of BLEU that's not exactly BLEU =)

Comment: To take some sort of mean of the scores, there're several strategies, here's a few https://github.com/alvations/meanie See also http://www.aclweb.org/old_anthology/W/W15/W15-30.pdf#page=282 the possibilities of computing a corpus level score from sentence level score is sorta endless ;P